# Use shell built-in time while checking exit status of a function and suppressing output

Tags: bash, time

I am attempting to do the following in a bash script and am wondering if it is possible:

- Time the output of a command (in this case, mysql) using `time`
- Suppress the stdout output of the command
- Capture the stderr output of the command in case of an error
- Check the exit status code of the command after running it

This is a complex chain and I haven't had much luck getting it all to work together. I can get the status code to work if I cease using time.

This is what I had so far:

```
# the setup
TIMEFORMAT=%R
MYSQL=mysql <options>

# execute and time a query (does more than is listed here)
function executeQuery {

  TIME=$( time ( $MYSQL "$1" 2>&1 | tee /tmp/somefile.txt > /dev/null ) 2>&1 )

  # do something with $?

}
```

I am redirecting any error response from the command to a file using tee, and then sending the resulting stdout to /dev/null. I am then redirecting the time command's stderr to stdout, which should end up in $TIME.

Now if I change that line to something like:

```
  TIME=$( time ( $MYSQL "$1" 2>&1 | tee /tmp/somefile.txt > /dev/null; exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]} ) 2>&1 )
```

It correctly sends back the exit code from mysql, but breaks the time command.

Is this even possible? Have I missed something? Hopefully the goal is clear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

bash `time` is a major PITA.  Its output isn't redirectable without nasty shell hacks like your multiple levels of subshells.  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/032 suggests that the correct answer is:

```
TIME = $( ( time $MYSQL "$1" 2>&1 | tee /tmp/somefile.txt > /dev/null; exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]} ) 2>&1 )
```

Note that bash `time` takes an entire pipeline as an argument, so placing the subshell after the time invocation is incorrect.

This was tested with

```
TIME = $( ( time ls /asdfasfdsfs 2>&1 | tee asdf 2>&1 >/dev/null ; exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]} ) 2>&1 );
echo $?;
echo $TIME
```

Which gave me

```
2
real 0m0.003s user 0m0.004s sys 0m0.004s
```

Comment: Worked perfectly -- many thanks! Looks like the only thing I was missing was moving time into the same subshell as the command chain. Makes sense now that I think about it.

Comment: why not just use the external time command instead? solves most problems with the built in time cmd.